# How to share jboss over network

Tags: java, service, jboss, share

I have jboss running on my machine on port 8080, i wanted to share jboss server on network,
So that i ran jboss service using jbossws-native-4.0.2 but i am still not able to access jboss server on network, please help.

Comment: This is likely a firewall configuration issue and belongs on [sf]

Comment: i found solution here http://cybergrams.blogspot.in/2011/09/how-to-access-jboss-as-7-on-lan-network.html
by the way thank you for reply

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use the option -b 0.0.0.0 when starting jboss (run.sh or run.bat) this binds the port to all network interfaces. Default is localhost thats why you can't reach the server over the network.