# Reach JBoss EAP 6 server in local network

Tags: java, networking, mobile, jboss, jboss-eap-6

I have a Java application running on JBoss EAP 6 which I can "hit" from mobile app on chrome using urls like: `127.0.0.1:8280/myAwesomeJavaApp/coolService` ...  so when I package the app I am using urls like this

`192.168.1.64:8280/myAwesomeJavaApp/coolService` `//this is not working`

`192.168.1.64` `// this gets me to my localhost`

(connected to WiFi (testing purposes))

I can access all other Apache web apps in my localhost , but can't consume JBoss EAP 6 services.

What am I missing ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Start Jboss server with -b 0.0.0.0**

```
./standalone.sh -b.0.0.0.0
```

[How to share jboss over network](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11357314/how-to-share-jboss-over-network)

Answer (score 0):

I am using service script:

```
JBOSS_HOST_CONFIG=host-master.xml
JBOSS_BIND_IP=0.0.0.0
JBOSS_NODE_NAME=master
JBOSS_USER=root
JBOSS_HOME=/opt/jboss-eap-6.4   


#!/bin/sh
#
# JBoss domain control script
#
# chkconfig: - 80 20
# description: JBoss AS Domain
# processname: domain
# pidfile: /var/run/jboss-as/jboss-as-domain.pid
# config: /etc/jboss-as/jboss-as.conf

# Source function library.
#. /etc/init.d/functions

# Load Java configuration.
[ -r /etc/java/java.conf ] && . /etc/java/java.conf
export JAVA_HOME

# Load JBoss AS init.d configuration.
if [ -z "$JBOSS_CONF" ]; then
  JBOSS_CONF="/etc/jboss-as/jboss-as.conf"
fi

[ -r "$JBOSS_CONF" ] && . "${JBOSS_CONF}"

# Set defaults.

if [ -z "$JBOSS_HOME" ]; then
  JBOSS_HOME=/usr/share/jboss-as
fi
export JBOSS_HOME

if [ -z "$JBOSS_PIDFILE" ]; then
  JBOSS_PIDFILE=/var/run/jboss-as/jboss-as-domain.pid
fi
export JBOSS_PIDFILE

if [ -z "$JBOSS_CONSOLE_LOG" ]; then
  JBOSS_CONSOLE_LOG=/var/log/jboss-as/console.log
fi

if [ -z "$STARTUP_WAIT" ]; then
  STARTUP_WAIT=60
fi

if [ -z "$SHUTDOWN_WAIT" ]; then
  SHUTDOWN_WAIT=30
fi

if [ -z "$JBOSS_DOMAIN_CONFIG" ]; then
  JBOSS_DOMAIN_CONFIG=domain.xml
fi

if [ -z "$JBOSS_HOST_CONFIG" ]; then
  JBOSS_HOST_CONFIG=host.xml
fi

if [ -z "$JBOSS_BIND_IP" ]; then
  JBOSS_BIND_IP=
fi

if [ -z "$JBOSS_NODE_NAME" ]; then
  JBOSS_NODE_NAME=
fi

JBOSS_SCRIPT=$JBOSS_HOME/bin/domain.sh

prog='jboss-as'

CMD_PREFIX=''

if [ ! -z "$JBOSS_USER" ]; then
  if [ -x /etc/rc.d/init.d/functions ]; then
    CMD_PREFIX="daemon --user $JBOSS_USER"
  else
    CMD_PREFIX="su - $JBOSS_USER -c"
  fi
fi

start() {
  echo -n "Starting $prog: "
  if [ -f $JBOSS_PIDFILE ]; then
    read ppid < $JBOSS_PIDFILE
    if [ `ps --pid $ppid 2> /dev/null | grep -c $ppid 2> /dev/null` -eq '1' ]; then
      echo -n "$prog is already running"
      
      echo 'failure!'
      return 1
    else
      rm -f $JBOSS_PIDFILE
    fi
  fi
  mkdir -p $(dirname $JBOSS_CONSOLE_LOG)
  cat /dev/null > $JBOSS_CONSOLE_LOG

  mkdir -p $(dirname $JBOSS_PIDFILE)
  chown $JBOSS_USER $(dirname $JBOSS_PIDFILE) || true
  #$CMD_PREFIX JBOSS_PIDFILE=$JBOSS_PIDFILE $JBOSS_SCRIPT 2>&1 > $JBOSS_CONSOLE_LOG &
  #$CMD_PREFIX JBOSS_PIDFILE=$JBOSS_PIDFILE $JBOSS_SCRIPT &

  if [ ! -z "$JBOSS_USER" ]; then
    if [ -r /etc/rc.d/init.d/functions ]; then
      daemon --user $JBOSS_USER LAUNCH_JBOSS_IN_BACKGROUND=1 JBOSS_PIDFILE=$JBOSS_PIDFILE $JBOSS_SCRIPT -b $JBOSS_BIND_IP -Djbos.node.name=$JBOSS_NODE_NAME --domain-config=$JBOSS_DOMAIN_CONFIG --host-config=$JBOSS_HOST_CONFIG 2>&1 > $JBOSS_CONSOLE_LOG &
    else
      su - $JBOSS_USER -c "LAUNCH_JBOSS_IN_BACKGROUND=1 JBOSS_PIDFILE=$JBOSS_PIDFILE $JBOSS_SCRIPT -b $JBOSS_BIND_IP -Djbos.node.name=$JBOSS_NODE_NAME --domain-config=$JBOSS_DOMAIN_CONFIG --host-config=$JBOSS_HOST_CONFIG" 2>&1 > $JBOSS_CONSOLE_LOG &
    fi
  fi

  count=0
  launched=false

  until [ $count -gt $STARTUP_WAIT ]
  do
    grep 'JBAS015874:' $JBOSS_CONSOLE_LOG > /dev/null
    if [ $? -eq 0 ] ; then
      launched=true
      break
    fi
    sleep 1
    count=$(($count+1))
  done

  if [ "$launched" = "false" ] ; then
    echo "$prog failed to startup in the time allotted"

    echo 'failure!'
    return 7
  fi

  echo 'successfuly done!'
  return 0
}

stop() {
  echo -n $"Stopping $prog: "
  count=0;

  if [ -f $JBOSS_PIDFILE ]; then
    read kpid < $JBOSS_PIDFILE
    let kwait=$SHUTDOWN_WAIT

    # Try issuing SIGTERM

    kill -15 $kpid
    until [ `ps --pid $kpid 2> /dev/null | grep -c $kpid 2> /dev/null` -eq '0' ] || [ $count -gt $kwait ]
    do
      sleep 1
      let count=$count+1;
    done

    if [ $count -gt $kwait ]; then
      kill -9 $kpid
    fi
  fi
  rm -f $JBOSS_PIDFILE
  echo 'successfuly done!'
  echo
}

status() {
  if [ -f $JBOSS_PIDFILE ]; then
    read ppid < $JBOSS_PIDFILE
    if [ `ps --pid $ppid 2> /dev/null | grep -c $ppid 2> /dev/null` -eq '1' ]; then
      echo "$prog is running (pid $ppid)"
      return 0
    else
      echo "$prog dead but pid file exists"
      return 1
    fi
  fi
  echo "$prog is not running"
  return 3
}

case "$1" in
  start)
      start
      ;;
  stop)
      stop
      ;;
  restart)
      $0 stop
      $0 start
      ;;
  status)
      status
      ;;
  *)
      ## If no parameters are given, print which are avaiable.
      echo "Usage: $0 {start|stop|status|restart|reload}"
      exit 1
      ;;
esac
```

and start with:

```
/etc/init.d/jbosseap6 start
```