# Unable to configure standalone JBoss AS7 instance to be reachable from outside network

Tags: java, linux, ubuntu, jboss, wildfly

I've been trying for a few days now to configure a development JBoss working space on my Linux Ubuntu server (both AS7 and WildFly 8), but I can't seem to be able to configure it so that I can see the web-facing ports outside of the local network. I've looked through several tutorials and pages here on stackoverflow, and they all seem to point to these lines in standalone.xml:

```
452     <interfaces>
453         <interface name="management">
454             <inet-address value="${jboss.bind.address.management:127.0.0.1}"/>
455         </interface>
456         <interface name="public">
457             <inet-address value="${jboss.bind.address:127.0.0.1}"/>
458         </interface>
459         <!-- TODO - only show this if the jacorb subsystem is added  -->
460         <interface name="unsecure">
461             <!--
462               ~  Used for IIOP sockets in the standard configuration.
463               ~                  To secure JacORB you need to setup SSL
464               -->
465             <inet-address value="${jboss.bind.address.unsecure:127.0.0.1}"/>
466         </interface>
467     </interfaces>
```

I've tried several different solutions, changing the inet-address value  to point to 0.0.0.0 like so

```
458             <inet-address value="${jboss.bind.address:0.0.0.0}"/>
```

as well as using the `<any-address/>` and `<any-ipv4-address/>` tag. I've also tried running the server with the -b 0.0.0.0 option. It appears that the changes take with all of these solutions, but when I try to visit the server by typing the IP address with port 9990, I still can't reach the admin console. I believe that the correct changes are being made with respect to interface-binding because on start-up it says

```
14:24:36,801 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) JBAS015951: Admin console listening on http://0.0.0.0:9990
```

I also know that the server is physically reachable because when I simply type in the IP, I can see the /var/www directory structure.

When I use netstat | grep 9990, I get:

```
tcp        0      0 *:9990                  *:*                     LISTEN      9519/java
```

Can anyone give me any suggestions as to why I am not able to reach the admin console? I've tried the solutions listed here:
[Can't access JBoss AS 7 from remote machine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21210649/cant-access-jboss-as-7-from-remote-machine)
and here:
[How to share jboss over network](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11357314/how-to-share-jboss-over-network)

UPDATE: The result of the command `iptables -L -v -n` is:

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 1736K packets, 1702M bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 1402K packets, 149M bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
```

Comment: how you are starting server? did you try `-b 0.0.0.0` with start server?

`.\standalone.sh -b 0.0.0.0`

Comment: @Neeraj I have indeed tried that option to no result, I still can't view the server on JBoss's ports, the command I'm running from $JBOSS_HOME is bin/standalone.sh -b 0.0.0.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not pretty sure what do you mean by:

> I also know that the server is physically reachable because when I
>   simply type in the IP, I can see the /var/www directory structure.

Are you trying reaching the server through FTP/SFTP , that's why you mention the /var/www folder ?
Can you make a list addresses which you have tried ? is http://domain.com:8080 (The Root Web app) reachable ? If so it could be a matter of a firewall rule blocking port 8080.
Try running as root:

```
/etc.rc.d/init.d/iptables stop
```

And see if you can reach the Administration console. I've published a small checklist of things to do to [reach jboss over a network](http://www.mastertheboss.com/jboss-server/jboss-configuration/how-to-access-jboss-as-over-a-network). Hope it helps

Comment: Sorry, what I mean is that if I have something like index.php sitting in /var/www/ then it will show up if I type just the IP address into the address bar. So I know that I'm getting past the server's network firewall at least. I can also FTP/SFTP and SSH. I don't use the network utilities much, but that command you suggested just returned "No such file or directory" I'll add the result of iptables to my original question though for more info.

Comment: Ok, you are able to reach an index.jsp page in the document root but that is going through port 80 or 8080 which are usually allowed by firewall. My suspect is that you have a rule blocking port 9990. You might try switching the management interface port to one that you have checked it is allowed traffic.

Comment: Hey it looks like you were correct. My firewall was not set up to allow TCP on port 8080 or 9990. This was the last thing I checked because I swear I've had it configured before, I've a few applications on there that I host with JBoss that I've seen remotely. Oh well, thank you for your time :)